# KCV Value - 3DES Encryption

Tags: .net, security, encryption

What is KCV (Key Check Value) in the context of 3-DES Encryption? Is there good documentation on what is KCV and how it can be used in 3-DES Encryption?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"6.15 Key Check Value
 Purpose: The data is used to prove that a card/processor has access to aspecific DES key value.
Format: Binary, 3 bytes
Contents: The three leftmost bytes of the result of encrypting eight bytes of zeros by the DES key concerned" ([source](http://www.scribd.com/doc/19132766/EMV-CPS-v11-20070720))
__
"The Key Check Value for any DES key will be computed by encrypting 8 bytes of '00' using ECB 3DES with the key concerned" ([source](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=6503685))
__
"The key check value (abbreviated KCV or CV) of a DES/3DES key is the result of encrypting 16 hexadecimal zeroes using the key. For example, the key check value of the single-length DES key 0123456789ABCDEF is equal to D5D44FF720683D0D. This information is useful when transmitting DES/3DES keys in an encrypted fashion and is usually send by the sender to ensure that the recipient has correctly received the key." ([source](http://eftcalculator.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=key%20check%20value))
__
To me, it seems this is some sort of [checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum).

Comment: You are right about about checksum. But if you want any others hash algorithm is possible for this purposes. Its not correct to transfer encrypted key via opened chanells.

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry: you would obviously only transfer or show the first x bytes of the blockencrypt, not the key.

Comment: @all - Sorry for the delay.. I have accepted the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

KCV's are used within e.g. the PKCS#11 standard for hardware security devices. Imagine you need to import secret keys, possibly in multiple parts. Then you need to verify that the import succeeded. You simply check a block encrypt of all zeros (or the leftmost part of it) against a previously calculated KCV value. As symmetric algorithms are supposed to be invulnerable against known plain text/cipher text attacks, you don't leak any information about the key.

For hardware security devices the keys are normally not extractable; they may therefore not be available for hash methods, or the hash method itself may not even be available. So performing a key encryption on all zero's is a nice method of creating a secure checksum. For other keys, such as RSA keys, hashing (SHA-1) is normally used instead of encryption to identify the (value of the) key.

In software you can simply create a block containing only zero's and then perform ECB encryption or CBC encryption with an IV set to all zero's. Then take x bytes as the KCV. The number of bytes in the KCV depends on the standard used. If you use less than 3 bytes you may run into keys with the same value even by accident.

Note that a KCV does leak a bit of information; it shows what a ciphertext encryption a block of all zero's looks like. If you perform CBC encryption with a random IV, that should not matter much. On the other hand, if you use CTR mode encryption with a zero IV, you might leak the first 3 bytes of the key stream (and therefore plaintext).

Lets keep in line with RobIII: [source](ftp://ftp.rsasecurity.com/pub/pkcs/pkcs-11/v2-30/pkcs-11v2-30b-d6.pdf) (note: FTP)