# Calculating KCV with DES Key

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, des

I'm having a problem with generating a KCV for a DES key in C#.NET

In reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11507155/kcv-value-3des-encryption) answer, the KCV for the DES key **"0123456789ABCDEF"** is **"D5D44F"** (as only the first 3 bytes are considered) and it is generated with a block containing 64bits of "0". To verify that that is the correct value, I also checked using this tool, which gave me the same result:

http://www.emvlab.org/keyshares/?combined=0123456789ABCDEF&combined_kcv=&one=&one_kcv=&two=&two_kcv=&three=&three_kcv=&numcomp=three&parity=ignore&action=Split

So I'm satisfied that I'm supposed to get a KCV of D5D44F.

Now, when I attempt to implement this in C#.NET, I get a different value entirely. I end up with **"7217BF"**

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(GetKCVDES());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static string GetKCVDES()
        {
            byte[] k = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF };
            byte[] i = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
            byte[] d = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

            DES des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, des.CreateEncryptor(k, i), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream);

            writer.Write(d);
            writer.Flush();
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            writer.Flush();
            return ByteArrayToString(memoryStream.GetBuffer()).Remove(6);
        }

        public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
        {
            StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
            foreach (byte b in ba)
                hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
            return hex.ToString().ToUpper();
        }
    }
}
```

The ByteArrayToString function just converts the byte array into a Hex string. I also inspected the Byte array before it got passed through to make sure the ByteArrayToString method is not giving a different output.

I've also tried explicitly forcing both ECB and CBC modes for the DES CSP, but I got the same result either way.

Is there something I've implemented incorrectly with the DES CSP?

Comment: Have you tried to use `TransformBlock` after you've created the Encryptor instance using `CreateEncryptor` in ECB mode? No need for all these streams here.

Comment: Thanks owlstead, I seem to have resolved it from your advice. I haven't yet implemented the TransformBlock function, but refactoring to remove one of the streams seems to have fixed it. Posting the answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to owlstead's comment, I removed the StreamWriter (to start getting rid of the streams) from the function and it's now giving the expected output.

I don't yet fully understand how these Stream objects work, so I don't know the actual reason why it now works, but with this update to the GetKCVDES function I get the KCV that I'm meant to be getting (I also simplified it a bit more with the using statement):

```
public static string GetKCVDES()
{
    byte[] key = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x23, 0x45, 0x67, 0x89, 0xAB, 0xCD, 0xEF };
    byte[] iv = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
    byte[] data = new byte[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

    DES des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, des.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cryptoStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            return ByteArrayToString(memoryStream.ToArray()).Remove(6);
        }
    }
}
```